# Building up a string non-sequentially?

Tags: java, string, replace, build

For example:

You're given a word and `Set` of letters. If the word contains letters that are not within the `Set`, then those letters are "replaced" with dashes. You're not actually supposed to change the given word, but create a new `String` that reflects those changes.

Say you were given a word: "magikarp". The `Set` contains the letters 'm', 'k', 'p'. The String that you would return would be "m---k--p".

How would you accomplish this by utilizing only a `String` and `String` methods? I also can't use any external libraries.

It is more intuitive to me to use arrays, but this has to be performed by building up a `String` instead of building any extra data structures for the sake of efficiency.

This is how I approached it (working solution but not done by building up a `String`), for further clarification:

```
public String getPattern (SortedSet<Character> guesses, String word) {
    char[] pattern = word.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) {
            if (!guesses.contains(pattern[i])) {
                pattern[i] = '-';
            }
        }
    // Pads each character in the generated String with spaces and trims
    // the leading and trailing spaces. 
    return new String(pattern).replace("", "").trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is, how would you approach this without using extra data structures?

Comment: Define "extra data structures". What is not allowed? Can we use a `StringBuilder`? Can we use Java 8 Stream? Can we use an array? Can we use a laser beam shifting bits?

Comment: Essentially, you can only use `String`s and `String` methods. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Should I just delete this question? I'm happy to clarify any questions or details that I may have left out but from the downvotes, it seems like this wasn't a good question to post

Comment: Or that this isn't the right place to post this sort of question

Comment: No, it's just that the question is _unclear_. Define exactly what you want, our crystal ball is broken.

Comment: I'm sorry if this question was phrased in a way that sounded like it expected too much or something?

Comment: Again, if you need details, please, just ask

Comment: Could you please specify what you are unsure about?

Comment: I don't see why you used the term "non-sequentially". But like I said, I think the question is clear.

Comment: Oh, "building up a String": does that mean one character at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use what String already provides, a method to get each character and a method to replace a specifc character with another:

```
public String getPattern (Set<Character> guesses, String word) {
    for (int i=0; i<word.length(); ++i) {
         char c = word.charAt(i);
         if (!guesses.contains(c)) 
             word = word.replace(c, '-');
    }
    return word;
}
```

Its not very efficient because it will create a new string instance for every character that needs to be replaced. For efficiency using a StringBuilder would be better.

Answer (score 2):

How about building a regex String from the Set of characters, and using that as a param to the String.replaceAll method to return the filtered String?

```
    Set<Character> letters = new HashSet<>();
    letters.add('m');
    letters.add('k');
    letters.add('p');

    String filter = "[^(";
    for (Character letter : letters) {
        filter += letter;
    }
    filter += ")]";

    String toBeReplaced = "magikarp";

    String result = toBeReplaced.replaceAll(filter, "-");
```

Comment: I love it! But would that `filter` be an "extra data structure"? OP?

Comment: Build the regex with regex, too! regex = "[^" + guesses.toString().replaceAll("[\\\[\\\],\s]", "") + "]"; (dang backslashes in comments are messed up)

Answer (score 1):

This is most certainly not the best way to approach the problem, except that it "builds up the String".

```
String newWord = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    char c = word.charAt(i);
    newWord = newWord + (
        guesses.contains(c) ? c : '-'
    );
}
```

This approach creates a new `String` instance on each letter rather than doing a quick replace. But it "builds it up".